# C# - Exportar em PDF um relatório do Report View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, reportviewer

```
public frmPedioVenda()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void frmPedioVenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void bntPesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PedidoVendaPHTableAdapter.Fill_ph
    (
        this.PedidoVendaDataSet1.PedidoVendaPH, txtPedido.Text
    );
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Aqui eu já crio o relatório e visualizo:

```
this.mexpedicao_saida1TableAdapter.Fill(
    this.sistemaquerubimDataSet2.mexpedicao_saida1
);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Qual é a sua duvida?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Oi amigo! Preciso exportar em PDF automaticamente um relatório do Report View em C#. e que essa rotina exporte em pdf e salve o arquivo em alguma pasta. Você pode me ajudar, por favor!?

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa é um modulo de rotina de serviços agendados.
Por exemplo, preciso que todos os dias 00:00 seja gerado um relatório dos pedidos do dia.
O que precisa?

**1. Pesquisa dos pedidos do dia no banco de dados.**
https://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-parametros-no-sqlcommand-em-csharp/28440

**2. Código para gerar o relatório em PDF.**
Seu código

**3. Código para salvar o relatório em uma pasta.**
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3684/trabalhando-com-arquivos-e-diretorios-em-csharp.aspx

**4. Serviço agendado (Task Schedule) que gerará o relatório diariamente. Recomendo Quartz, mas pode usar o Hangfire mesmo.**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/job-scheduling-in-Asp-Net-mvc-with-quartz-net/